# .mdb - Access - database appending # on image file

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm creating a website that interfaces with a .mdb database.  I have a field that is using the data type "hyperlink" and pointing to a relative link for an image I want displayed.  For some reason the link is appearing and not the image and there is a # that is being prepended and appended on each URL. I thought maybe the path was wrong but even if I change it I don't get the image.  The mdb file also wants to add http:// to every link.

www.centuryautosd.com  < URL

thanks for any help.
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlink fields (columns) in Access store the data in the format:

```
Name of hyperlink#http://example.com#
```

I generally prefer to use textfields, because it is easy enough to follow a hyperlink on a form, if required, and the field (column) is a lot easier to edit and maintain.

Comment: Note also that hyperlink fields are actually memo fields under the hood. This makes sense since it's very easy for a URL to exceed 255 characters, so if you're storing the URL in plain old text instead of a hyperlink field, you'll probably want to use a memo field, anyway. You won't gain anything in efficiency, but as @Remou points out, it's much simpler to work with.

Comment: I'm still not getting the image to come out.  If you go to http://www.centuryautosd.com/see_autos.asp?autoLable=Cadillac you can see what I mean.  How can I get this to show the image?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not seem to have an image at http://www.centuryautosd.com/images/mock-car.jpg where are your images stored?

Comment: duh!  what a dingle fritz - however, come to find out I needed to write a bit of asp code to get it to come out.  I got it done.  thanks for the help!